# Flag on deleted question showing in 10K queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, deleted-questions, 10k-tools

There's something odd with [this post that's current showing in the flag queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538988/how-to-build-fuse-esb-servicemix-4-4-1) to 10K users.

[image]

It's deleted but I'm still seeing the flag which is odd given it was deleted two days ago. It doesn't look like it's a case of the usual "deleted whilst I was reading" scenario.

Furthermore the post itself shows no evidence of who deleted it. Usually for deleted questions it shows this, even for self-deletes.

1. Is this intentional that 10K users can see this flag? There doesn't seem to be anything useful I can do with a flag like that on a closed question. I can't vote or vote to close and without knowing who deleted it salvaging edits are out too.
2. Why doesn't it show who deleted it? Is it the [auto-deletion process for low scored unanswered question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)s? If yes shouldn't that indicate the source of the deletion ([Community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)?) *and* clear the pending close flags?

Comment: @Oded - 48 hours worth of aggressive?

Comment: w00t! http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/897952#897952 :-P

Comment: We've got the same issue in the mod queue.  I bet this is a dupe, but I don't want to hunt it down.  I don't consider it a bug, but a FR to stop doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10k users were seeing all posts with moderator flags on them, whether they were deleted or not.

Next build corrects this issue, so you shouldn't be seeing deleted posts on the 10k tools unless you are a moderator.